# Abstract class input for start

Tags: java

I have an abstract class  like this

```
public abstract class Abstractclass
{
    public Abstractclass(int init)
    {
    }
}

public class test extends Abstractclass
{//errors on the line above

}
```

and a class that extends it in the class that extends the original one I get an error saying that the var was incorrect or something like that is there any work around to this?

Edit: the error says constructor Abstractclass in class game.Abstractclass cannot be applied to given types

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting? Where's the code for the subclass?

Comment: Show the class on which you are getting the error.

Comment: Your question is useless.  **What error do you get?**

Comment: Also, generally the constructor for an abstract class should be `protected` not `public`.

Comment: People will ignore this until you show the code on which you are getting the error.

Comment: Show us your `game.Abstractclass`.

Comment: Posting things like 'I get an error saying that the var was incorrect or something like that' is just a complete waste of everybody's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AbstractClass does not have a default constructor. It's only constructor takes one argument. Therefore class `test` must also have a constructor which calls `super` and passes a `int`.